# How to run R from the windows command prompt?

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1

I want to run R from the command prompt in Windows 8.1.  I am logged in as an administrator, I started cmd.exe with the "Run as administrator" option, the path to the folder containing R.exe has been appended to my path environment variable, and my current directory is the folder that contains R.exe.  When I type the command `R.exe` Windows responds with the message "The system cannot find the path specified."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: run ProcessMonitor in background and look where Windows searches for R.exe: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645, http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor, http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Comment: @magicandre1981  Thanks for the links.  I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the same folder try executing `./R.exe` to explicitly denote that you're looking for the executable inside the current directory.